# how to group yii2 sql result into multiple arrays

Tags: yii2

I have two tables: `category` and `foods`. 
How do I get the following form yii2:

```
-lounch
--Lunch Box Muffins
--Wrap up Lunch
--....


-Fast food    
--Baking stone
--Chocolate pizza
--...
-...
```

My question is similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655657/multidimensional-array-to-group-categories-and-sub-categories)

Comment: please explain better your goal ..

Answer (score 0):

Here a form with 2 dropdown , data coming from `food` and `category`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'foodId')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map( Food::find()->all(), 'id','name_food')) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'categoryId')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'id', 'name_category')) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton( Yii::t('app', 'Assign') , ['class' =>  'btn btn-primary']) ?>
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```